# two ng-repeat in same

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am a problem, which in my view, is very complicated. I wanted to see other thoughts about.

Created fields with the angular formly, these same fields are generated by a policy to be dealt with, the problem to record this data, I would need two repeats or not, still have not found a way out for not using 2 repeats, my code below is one more try unsuccessfully:

Repeat:

```
                <md-card-content>

                    <h2 class="md-title">{{g.title}}</h2>

                    <div ng-repeat="f in g.fields and i in item.grupos.fields">

                        <field-create field="f" ng-model="i.model"></field-create>

                        <p>result: {{f | json}}</p>

                    </div>

                </md-card-content>

            </md-card>
```

If someone can be interested in helping me, I get more details from the rest of the code.

I hope ideas :)

UPDATED, NEW IDEIA, no sucess..

The problem is, I have recorded in my resource fields, which create fields dynamically. What I'm not getting is to record data in these fields.

1. a group of fields in the resource is created.
2. This field group is called in another view, a policy is whether the field is input, textarea or checkbox and renders the field.
3. When saving these fields have the same view are created other entries in the resource already with the data you enter in the fields.
4. Now my problem, I'm not able to show this data recorded in the view, because I have a repeat to check the recorded fields in the resource. I need another repeat to populate these fields.

I managed to explain as it is complicated.

i create Jsbin for help: http://jsbin.com/faquhizupo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Waaaay too much code. Reduce to bare minimum to illustrate your issue

Comment: I prefer to leave full, otherwise they can not understand the idea. Did you undersand?

Comment: When I see unjustifiably long-code-questions, I assume that you haven't done enough work yourself to try to reduce and isolate the problem. Which means, I won't spend my time as well. Good luck

Comment: Really not clear what the specific problem is

Comment: I also don't understand what the question is, but I'll point out that your `allDB.query()` and `allDB.get()` calls probably won't work. Your code expects a synchronous response from a server, but it won't get any because this is JavaScript. Research: "Promises" https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: The best way to get help with angular-formly is to follow the instructions here: http://help.angular-formly.com

Answer (score 1):

Your exact intent of showing up a large portion of code is not 100% clear. But I assume you are having difficulty in manipulating nested loops. 
If you want to have nested `ng-repeat', use the below syntax.

**JSON Object**

```
$scope.myDataSet = [
{
   "id" : 1234,
   "desc" : "My Description",
   "data": [
       {
          "sub_id" : "sub id 1",
          "field1" : "Value 1",
          "field2" : "Value 2"
       },
       {
          "sub_id" : "sub id 2",
          "field1" : "Value 3",
          "field2" : "Value 4"
       },
       {
          "sub_id" : "sub id 3",
          "field1" : "Value 5",
          "field2" : "Value 6"
       }
  ]
},
{
   "id" : 4567,
   "desc" : "My Description2",
   "data": [
       {
          "sub_id" : "sub id 3",
          "field1" : "Value 1",
          "field2" : "Value 2"
       },
       {
          "sub_id" : "sub id 4",
          "field1" : "Value 3",
          "field2" : "Value 4"
       },
       {
          "sub_id" : "sub id 5",
          "field1" : "Value 5",
          "field2" : "Value 6"
       }
  ]
}
];
```

This can be displayed in HTML as below,

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myDataSet track by $index">
   {{data.desc}}
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="record in data track by $index">
         <div>
            <h3>{record.sub_id}</h3>
            {{record.field1}}
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to access external loop items inside internal loop, that can be achieved as `$parent.$index`.